# How can I integrate stylecop 4.7 with TeamCity 7.0.3

Tags: .net, build, teamcity, stylecop

I've dowloaded the **stylecop** teamcity plugin from 
https://bitbucket.org/metaman/teamcitydotnetcontrib/overview

I've added it as a build step and am trying to make it scan my `cs. proj` files. Can you please help me with the file inclusion pattern. I've tried everything.

I've used a relative to the checkout folder path, used an absolute path with or without `ant` like wildcards, pointed it to `sln` files or `csproj` files, nothing works.

I've downloaded the plugin's source code, it does allow the usage of absolute or relative file paths.

My ultimate goal is to fail the build should **stylecop** find any error level problems withing the code, is that even possible?

Regards,

Peter

As backup I am thinking of using msbuild and hook stylecop from there

Answer (score 1):

Try;

```
**\*.csproj
```

in the `Files or wildcards` input.

(Yes I know this is a year late, but just in case it helps someone else)